# Closures & Destructuring — Destructured functions can't call each other?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, closures, destructuring

I have something like the following:

```
let MM = {
    a: function(){
        b();
    },
    b: function(){
        console.log('b');
    }
};

function makeClosure(M) {
    let { a, b } = M;

    function a2(){ b2() };
    function b2(){ console.log('b2'); };

    return function( arg ){
        if ( arg === 1 ) a();
        if ( arg === 2 ) a2();
    }
}

let c = makeClosure( MM );

////////////////////////////////////////////
// RESULTS

c( 1 ); // b() doesn't exist
c( 2 ); // b2() exists just fine
```

```js
let MM = {
  a: function(){
    b();
  },
  b: function(){
    console.log('b');
  }
};

function makeClosure(M) {
    let { a, b } = M;

    function a2(){ b2() };
    function b2(){ console.log('b2'); };

    return function( arg ){
        if ( arg === 1 ) a();
        if ( arg === 2 ) a2();
    }
}

let c = makeClosure( MM );

////////////////////////////////////////////
// RESULTS

c( 1 ); // b() doesn't exist
c( 2 ); // b2() exists just fine
```

Why do the above Results outcomes happen? I thought destructuring was supposed to be equivalent to declaration. Why is the destructured b not found by a? They exist in the same scope?

Is there any way to make this work? I would prefer to destructure for organizational reasons. I can't keep them as methods for various reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standalone function named `b` from the lexical scope of `MM.a`, so calling `a()` from `makeClosure` results in an error because no variable or function named `b` can be found from within the `a` function in `MM`.

One possibility would be to pass `a` the function to execute, that way `MM` doesn't rely on any outer variable:

```js
let MM = {
    a: function(someFn){
        someFn();
    },
    b: function(){
        console.log('b');
    }
};

function makeClosure(M) {
    let { a, b } = M;

    function a2(){ b2() };
    function b2(){ console.log('b2'); };

    return function( arg ){
        if ( arg === 1 ) a(b);
        if ( arg === 2 ) a2();
    }
}

let c = makeClosure( MM );
c(1);
c(2);
```

Another option would be to `call` `a` inside `makeClosure` with a calling context of an object which has a `b` property, just like `MM`, and have `MM.a` call `this.b`:

```js
let MM = {
    a: function(){
        this.b();
    },
    b: function(){
        console.log('b');
    }
};

function makeClosure(M) {
    let { a, b } = M;

    function a2(){ b2() };
    function b2(){ console.log('b2'); };

    return function( arg ){
        if ( arg === 1 ) a.call({ b });
        if ( arg === 2 ) a2();
    }
}

let c = makeClosure( MM );
c(1);
c(2);
```

The issue doesn't have anything to do with destructuring - it's just plain JS scoping rules.

Comment: I think I assumed too much based on the definition aspect of destructuring. I think what I really want is some way to import the methods as if they were literally defined at that line. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: When an answer helps you, consider marking it as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved.